# Eelasticsearch - how to remove specific alias from all indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I remove specific alias from all indices in ElasticSearch ? And then add new index with that alias ?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It seems like a valid question and the answer helped me (helped me see that the docs actually answered it, as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done via use of wildcard:

```
POST: /_aliases

{
 "actions" : [
    { "remove" : { "index" : "*", "alias" : "nameOfAlias" } },
    { "add" : { "index" : "nameOfNewIndex", "alias" : "nameOfAlias" } }
 ]
}
```